# What would be the reason behind the window service stop

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2003

I have an application named “LeafTest” which has Server Edition and Client Edition. The server Service is “Mss.exe” which is running under account “stepup” account which I checked from “services.msc”  and system configuration is 2003 server 32bit standard edition with SP2.  But yesterday means November 20 it suddenly stopped , I don’t know what is the reason behind it. 
When I checked my application logs I can see these errors just before it reported service stopped

The entries in **event log**  are

Following error also i can see somewhere

Event ID ( 8500 ) in Source ( LeafTest)
    cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry
    information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer.

When I go0gled somewhere its mentioning my application may not be installed properly or registered or I need to work with registry. Can any body tell me what will be the reason behind the service stpped by reading logs which i have posted

Comment: Is there a reason that you arent concerned about the access violation?

Comment: Did you write this application, or just install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service may halt if there is an unhandled exception.  Check that you are handling all exceptions.  Also, if the service uses any COM objects I have, in the past, had exceptions that could not be caught in my .NET 2.0 applications.

Comment: I think that the error code c0000005 is an access violation code as pointed out by Ritch Melton.

Comment: Was a windows update applied or security settings changed on the server?

Comment: It looks like your service stopped because the user was logged off and closed down services.  What happens if you set your service to run under the server's system account?

Comment: I'm very sorry, but could you re-phrase you question (above) because I don't understand?

Comment: I think that this is a windows server issue not C# winforms.  Try posting specific question under a tag of windows server.  My knowledge of windows server is very limited.

Comment: It maybe better to run the service under the 'Network Service' account instead if you have a client application that needs to interact with it.

Comment: Just a bit off-the-wall what if you run your service and then disconnect your network cable from the server?

Comment: "you mean local system account?" -> In control panel | services | <your service> | Properties 'Log On' tab and set 'This account:' to "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService".

Comment: I wanted to check that the service is not terminating because of a temporary network loss/outage.

Comment: Look for event 4201 in event viewer under system (this is the tcpip connected sucessfully which could only logically appear if it was not previously connected).